# Vue-Paginate how to import and use?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, vuejs2

I currently have a basic pagination system. But am looking to make it a little more complex by using - https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate#readme

But for some reason, I just cannot get it to work!

Right now, my working code looks like this -

```
<div v-if="totalPages() > 1" class="pagination-wrapper">
    <!-- <span v-if="showPreviousLink()" class="pagination-btn" v-on:click="updatePage(currentPage - 1)"><</span> -->

    <!-- <span v-if="showNextLink()" class="pagination-btn" v-on:click="updatePage(currentPage + 1)">></span> -->


    <div class="page-buttons-wrapper">
        <button v-if="currentPage > 0" class="page-button" v-on:click="updatePage(currentPage - 1)"><p class="light semibold"><</p></button>

        <button class="page-button" v-for="(page, index) in totalPages()" :key="index" v-on:click="updatePage(index)">
            <p class="light semibold">{{ index + 1}}</p>
        </button>

        <button v-if="currentPage < totalPages() - 1 " class="page-button" v-on:click="updatePage(currentPage + 1)"><p class="light semibold">></p></button>
    </div>
    <div class="page-count">
        <h6 class="dark-grey">Page {{ currentPage + 1}} of {{ totalPages() }}</h6>
    </div>

</div>
```

Essentially, there is a +1 for next, -1 for previous and "go to page X" per button. Which is fine. But I want to make it a bit more future proof (hence the hopes to use the above mentioned package.

The issue is, after installing via NPM and using even their basic text/example I cannot get it to work. (their demo is here https://jsfiddle.net/lokyoung/u3u3nzns/, even when copying it line for line I just cannot get it to work)

I am thinking maybe there is a specific way to use it? copying my code would basically just be the same as theirs on the demo. So no idea why it wont do anything :s

Comment: could you share the tried example in the component and main.js

Comment: Oh that is for my other temporary pagination I have in place that isn't exactly what i want/need. It is working, but is just a basic right and left arrow. I want something a little more advanced

Comment: could you be more specific

Comment: Yes sorry, give me 2 minutes and ill update my comment with more info! :)

Comment: please explain what do you expect and what's it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using this bootstrap version in my index.html:
    cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css